# Can/How to delete Apple Shared Support zip file?

Tags: macos, applications, big-sur

I have this file (seems like a macOS Big Sur dmg file), which takes loads of space and showed up from nowhere. How can I get rid of this file (is it even safe to delete it?). Searched from Google and found that SharedSupport folders should not be touched.

2017 Macbook Air; Big Sur version 10.15.7

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The file is located in `/Applications/Install macOS Big Sur.app`. You can delete the installer to reclaim the space.